# How can I get these numbers from this html website in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, bots, discord, discord.js

https://sky.lea.moe/api/Altpapier/ea805d40e8284d8d8e64e9fc8ac301ca/cakebag

How can I get these numbers? (Javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to get the HTML of the page to parse.

```js
function httpGet(url, done){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         done(xhttp.responseText);
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
httpGet("https://sky.lea.moe/api/Altpapier/ea805d40e8284d8d8e64e9fc8ac301ca/cakebag", function(data){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = data;
    var tds = div.querySelectorAll("table td");
    tds.forEach(td=>console.log(td.textContent));
});
```

You can also use the newer [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API.

```js
fetch("https://sky.lea.moe/api/Altpapier/ea805d40e8284d8d8e64e9fc8ac301ca/cakebag")
    .then(res=>res.text()).then(html=>{
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = html;
  var tds = div.querySelectorAll("table td");
  tds.forEach(td=>console.log(td.textContent));
});
```